# How to run neural network on gpu using compute shaders from ComputeSharp when there are so many layer connection weights?

Tags: c#, algorithm, neural-network, compute-shader

So I have a neural network I have created in C#. It can have upwards of 250k inputs once encoded. It can have a varying number of hidden layers with varying neurons per layer and usually 1 or 2 outputs. It's based on evolutionary neural networks(genetic networks). I am using compute sharp for c#. https://github.com/Sergio0694/ComputeSharp/wiki

So because each neuron in each layer is connected to all neurons in the previous layer. Then for example, 1 neuron in layer 2 has 250k weights and if there is 1000 neurons in layer 2, then that is a total of 250,000,000 weights just in those 2 layers. On top of that, if each weight is a float, thats 4 bytes * 250,000,000 = 1,000,000,000 Bytes , 1 Gigabyte for just the weights.

Since compute shaders only have texture 2d/3d arrays, no dictionaries, how to create the neuron-weight connections on a gpu?

I could easily create a buffer to hold all neurons in layer 1 and layer 2, thats easy. However creating the weight connections seems harder since I can't just use a key,value system. It also varies so I can't just hardcode 1000 neuron connections. There is also a limit in texture2d/3d of I believe 4096 on each axis which is too small to hold a single neurons weights in layer 2 to layer 1 since it would have 250k weights.

Any ideas how to create the weight connections with the compute shader limitations. Are compute shaders just not a good fit for this?

Comment: I guess the best way is to call into cudnn (at least for nvidia gpus).
Think about a layer as a big linear transformation (aka a matrix) and do linear algebra.

Comment: Don't have an nvidia gpu, lol. Currently testing an idea using structs. Basically 1 "neurons struct" holds neuron info like activation level, neuron_bias, activation type(sigmoid, tanh, relu etc...), another "layers struct" holds the index of layer 1 neuron and layer 2 neuron as well as the weight. Have to hardcode the number of layers though but thats easy, any unused layers are just not calculated.

Comment: As Unlikus says, the conceptual model to use is matrix multiplication. The details depend on what API you want to use. But this really depend on what the goal is. If you want best performance you should use an existing, well optimized library on known hardware. But if this is for learning, and you don't want to wait as long, you might consider just optimizing your current implementation. Going from dictionaries to arrays with SIMD operations should give a decent speedup without needing to learn GPU programming.

Comment: Thanks, I might just do that and try SIMD first.